# Count number of found paths with find in bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I wanted to search for some files recursively and count the number of occurrences that I found.
To find the files I did:

`file=$(find . -iname "*.xml")`

Now I'd like to store the number of occurrences in another variable. I just don't know how. I tried:

`n=$(echo $file | wc -l)`

but I don't think that's the right way...

Super grateful for any help:)

Comment: `echo $file | wc -l` will always return `1` -- because the variable is **unquoted**, the shell will subject the variable contents to [word splitting]() which will transform all sequences of whitespace (including newlines) into single spaces. Refer to [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667) for all the gory details.

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo in your command: the `}` is not correct.

With it removed, your attempt is pretty close, but you have to quote the variable expansion to preserve linebreaks:

```sh
files=$(find . -iname '*.xml')
n=$(echo "$files" | wc -l)
echo "$n"
```

This can still break, though, for files with exotic names – for example including a newline in the filename. To make it robust for all possible filenames, you could do this (requires GNU `find`):

```sh
files=$(find . -iname '*.xml' -printf '.')
echo "${#files}"
```

This prints a single `.` for each file found and then counts these periods.

Alternatively, if you don't have GNU `find`, you could use null byte separation for filenames and read them into an array:

```sh
readarray -d '' files < <(find . -iname '*.xml' -print0)
echo "${#files[@]}"
```

or for older version of Bash where `readarray` can't specify the delimiter to use (any Bash older than 4.4):

```sh
while IFS= read -r -d '' fname; do
    files+=("$fname")
done < <(find . -iname '*.xml' -print0)
echo "${#files[@]}"
```

Comment: I'm just starting, but really liking bash. But there are so many options, that it's just overwhelming. Anyways, thank you so much!! 
Just one question (and I know there are a ton of ressouces out there), but still: 
Why did you put double quotes around "$files", instead of my $file ?

Comment: @Lenn Have a look at the output of this: `var=$'a\nb\nc'; echo "$var"; echo $var` – quoting prevents "word splitting", which can have a lot of undesired effects, such as replacing things like linebreaks with spaces – see the [question glenn linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/118235) for a ton of details. In this specific case, not quoting it prints just a single line and the result is always 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

# make an array
files=($(find . -name \*.xml -print))

# number of array elements
fcnt=${#files[@]}

echo files: "${files[@]}"
echo
echo fcnt: $fcnt
```

Comment: Fails dramatically with file names containing spaces, tabs or newlines.